# Jest mock addEventListener "DOM Content loaded" for tests inside this check

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to write unit tests for logic that occurs inside a check for 'DOMContentLoaded'

Code example:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // do stuff
    ...
});
```

In my tests I am already mocking the `window` object (as I have a util to set the window). So I was trying to mock `addEventListener` on my window mock:

```
jest.mock("./utils/window");
let mockWindow;
const mockWindowObject = {
  addEventListener: jest.fn().mockImplementation("DOMContentLoaded", () => true)
};


beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
    
  mockWindow = require("./utils/window").default;
  mockWindow.mockReturnValue(mockWindowObject);
    
  require("./myComponent");
});
```

So before each I am correctly mocking the window, and then returning the object which contains the mock function `addEventListener`. I think I'm making a mistake in the `mockImplementation` part but I'm not sure what:

```
addEventListener: jest.fn().mockImplementation("DOMContentLoaded", () => true)
```

Comment: Why not: Extract the handler as a separate function -> test that function?

Comment: @VLAZ I'm happy with my implementation of the logic, I don't want to change it. I just want to get past the DOMContentLoaded step to test the logic inside.

Comment: Show your logic inside `DOMContentLoaded` event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem using the [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) library.

If you want to check changes made in DOMContentLoaded Event, just implement a eventListener in your test:

```js
test('DOMContentLoaded changes', () => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // your checks here
  });
})
```

In my case, I just need to use the testing library selectors to verify my changes in DOM.

You can check this [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914#issuecomment-313786743).